# OrientDB - Using REST with Distributed Graph

Tags: php, rest, orientdb

I have a distributed graph with 2 nodes.
And I have defined some functions (http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Functions-Creation.html) 
I want to call them from my PHP webapp. 
I can use REST API to call them but I should specific the IP/PORT of node should use. Assume that I call to Node1.

But how I use all nodes IP/PORT so in case Node1 offline, the REST auto connect to Node2 to get data?

In case it is impossible. So can I do it with PHP API? I can't find any information about it in OrientDB Documents.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you working with OrientDb version 2.1 or 2.2 ?

Comment: I think you should check the connection to the node1 and if it were not online, you can connect to node2

Comment: @AlessandroRota Thanks for your suggestion. I use OrientDB 2.2.8. I see that Java API supports auto-switched to the next available node. It will be great if PHP support it too.

Comment: I see that OrientDB support multiple addresses. But seem that it is only supported by Java driver [use-multiple-addresses](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Distributed-Configuration.html#use-multiple-addresses)

Comment: @TanHo, you can just write a simple custom function in PHP to check the connection to the primary node.

Comment: @OleksandrGubchenko Thank you! Seem that it is a best way right now.